# Setting the choicebox value when using a list of objects

Tags: java, javafx, observable

I'm trying to set the value of my choiceBox.

It works when using plain Strings like this:

```
choiceBox.getItems.setAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList("a","b","c"));
choiceBox.setValue("a");
```

But it doesn't set the value (and no error) when using a Class to fill and set the choiceBox

```
ObservableList<Course> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
items.add(Course.getAll());

choiceBox.getItems().setAll(items);
choiceBox.setValue(schedule.getCourse());
```

also tried to use `shedule.getCourse().toString()` because the choiceBox uses the toString method to show the courses.

What part of my object does the `ChoiceBox` need?

My Course Class:

```
public class Course {

// Property Value Factory
public static final String PVF_NAME = "name";

private String name;

// == constructors ==

public Course(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

// == public methods ==

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public static Course fromString(String line) {
    return new Course(line);
}

// Getters & Setters

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: If you properly define your `Course` object, you just need to pass an actual `Course` object to the `setValue()` method. See my answer below.

Comment: Your `Course` object, however, appears to itself contain a list of courses? I do not think that is how you want to do this. The `Course` object should represent just one `Course`, not many.

Comment: @Zephyr I tried to simplify the code. It's a static function that reads from a file and calls fromString for each line and adds that object to a list and returns the list and the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override the `toString()` method for your object. The `ChoiceBox` will use that value for the list of options.

From there, you need to select the value of the `ChoiceBox` by passing it a refernece to the desired `Course` from the `coursesList`.

Below is a simple MCVE to demonstrate:

**Course.java:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Course {

    private StringProperty courseName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Course(String courseName) {
        this.courseName.set(courseName);
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty courseNameProperty() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName.set(courseName);
    }

    // The ChoiceBox uses the toString() method of our object to display options in the dropdown.
    // We need to override this method to return something more helpful.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return courseName.get();
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create the ChoiceBox
        ChoiceBox<Course> cbCourses = new ChoiceBox<>();

        // Sample list of Courses
        ObservableList<Course> coursesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // Set the list of Course items to the ChoiceBox
        cbCourses.setItems(coursesList);

        // Add the ChoiceBox to our root layout
        root.getChildren().add(cbCourses);

        // Now, let's add sample data to our list
        coursesList.addAll(
                new Course("Math"),
                new Course("History"),
                new Course("Science"),
                new Course("Geography")
        );

        // Now we can select our value. For this sample, we'll choose the 3rd item in the coursesList
        cbCourses.setValue(coursesList.get(2));

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

---

> **EDIT**

To select a `Course` by name, you will need a helper method to retrieve a matching `Course` from the `coursesList`.

**Using Java 8 Stream API:**

```
    private Course getCourseByName(String name, List<Course> courseList) {

    // This basically filters the list based on your filter criteria and returns the first match,
    // or null if none were found.
    return courseList.stream().filter(course ->
            course.getCourseName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

**Prior Java Versions:**

```
    private Course getCourseByName(String name, List<Course> courseList) {

    // Loop through all courses and compare the name. Return the Course if a match is found or null if not
    for (Course course : courseList) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(course.getCourseName())) {
            return course;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can now select the value using `cbCourses.setValue(getCourseByName("History", coursesList));`

---

> **EDIT #2:**

In an effort to staisfy *kleopatra's* critique, I'll post a more "proper" way to updating the displayed value for your `Course` objects. While I see nothing wrong with overriding `toString()` in most simple applications, especially if you've designed it in such a way that there is only one string representation you'll need for your objects, I'll add the other method here.

Instead of overriding the `toString()` method directly in your `Course` object, set the converter on the `ComboBox` itself:

```
    cbCourses.setConverter(new StringConverter<Course>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Course object) {
            return object.getCourseName();
        }

        @Override
        public Course fromString(String string) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

I do think this unnecessary in very simple applications, however, and have not needed it in my own real-world projects. It is the "right" way, however.

Comment: `cbCourses.setValue(coursesList.get(2));` works, but cbCourses.setValue(new Course("History")); doesn't. Is the only way to compare my Course with the list and get the index of the one I need?

Comment: You could create a helper method to retrieve a `Course` by name, of course. I'll edit my answer to show that as well.

Comment: no, plain wrong - never-ever override toString for application reasons (what would you do if the same item is shown in different contexts with different visualization requirements?) Instead, use configure the choicebox with a stringconverter